# Width inherit on fixed div doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

First, here is an example of what I have.
https://jsfiddle.net/1xyofup5/

Html code :

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div>
        Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content 
      </div>
      <div class="fixed">
        Other content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code :

```
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.container > div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.container > div > .fixed {
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: inherit;
}
```

**I can't change the html structure and I can only edit `.container > div` and `.container > div > .fixed` rules.**

How can I make the fixed div fit the width of his parent ? The `inherit` doesn't work.

Thanks !

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: you have no width set

Comment: @DaMaxContent width is set in the `.container`.

Comment: I think somebody is spam downvoting our solutions. I tried to upvote the others as they are not bad. I can't upvote mine

Comment: There are 5 answers right now, but the firsts are downvoted I don't know why. However, the only answer that provides a snippet and the modified fiddle is mine.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I don't really think a snippet is necessary. He only needs one line of code, but to your point, OP needs to select an answer

Comment: Also, Chris keeps updating his. As much as I hate to say it, he deserves the gold

Comment: @DaMaxContent you are wrong. A working example is neccessary and better in all cases, in questions and in answers. Please, read the stackoverflow FAQ. Right now, 6 identical answers....

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude You do not have to be strict about that FAQ. sometimes answers can be to lengthy. In his case, he only needed one line of code and explanation why it works. A snippet or fiddle is unneccesary

Comment: I just wish someone would have upvoted mine

Comment: @DaMaxContent, you should remove that comment. Don't accuse people.

Comment: @Chris done. It is just frustrating to think someone would be that selfish. They are good posts all of them.

Comment: @DaMaxContent your answer was upvoted by me, to make justice with your comment `I think somebody is spam downvoting our solutions. I tried to upvote the others as they are not bad. I can't upvote mine`.

Comment: My faith has been restored in stackoverflow... I approve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp)* on the `inherit` property:

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.

and *[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)*:

> The inherit CSS-value causes the element for which it is specified to take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It is allowed on every CSS property.
>
> For inherited properties, this reinforces the default behavior, and is only needed to override another rule.  For non-inherited properties, this specifies a behavior that typically makes relatively little sense and you may consider using initial instead, or unset on the all property.
>
> Inheritance is always from the parent element in the document tree, even when the parent element is not the containing block.

In your case, the inherited value to `fixed` is not what you want because its' direct parent (`.container > div`) doesn't have a a `width` set, and so it gets the default value of `auto`.

I see two simple solutions:

### Option 1

Inherit the width throughout all children. So add this:

```
.container > div {
  width: inherit;
}
```

That way, the width of `container` will be inherited twice down to the `fixed` element.

[**Option 1 demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/27qf284p/2/)

---

### Option 2

Give `.container > div` its' own width:

```
.container > div {
  width: 300px;
}
```

[**Option 2 demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/27qf284p/1/)

Comment: I should have gone full out just your answer. Oh well

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it defining a width in the parent, so:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.container > div {
    width: 340px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.container > div > .fixed {
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: inherit;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div>
       Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content Some content 
      </div>
      <div class="fixed">
        Other content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See your fiddle edited:

https://jsfiddle.net/1xyofup5/1/

I've defined the `.container > div` with a width that's will be inherited by `.fixed`. See `box-sizing` property to lead with paddings.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to fix this.

The simple fix is to add **`width:inherit`** to the parent div:

```
.container > div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: inherit;            <<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

What is wrong with your snippet is that the `inherit` value takes the value of the parent. In the parent of your snippet, you do not have a width defined, so it is the CSS default of `width:auto`

you can also specify the width in the parent div to be like:

```
.container > div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 350px;            <<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

you can also specify the width of `.fixed`, but I am sure that is not what you want to do

Answer (score -1):

`inherit` doesn't work like you say, so just explicitly set it:

```
.container > div > .fixed {
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 330px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

The width is adjusted for your padding. I've added the negative margin purely to line up the red and green borders.

Answer (score -1):

All `div`s leading up to the fixed one should have `width: inherit`.