# Trying to inherit width to an img tag in css

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I'm trying to inherit the width of an id to an img tag so that the image is never bigger than the id around it. But somehow inherit is not working but when I use width with an absolute value like 580px it works.
I'm wondering why it doesn't work.

this is how it looks in chrome inspector.

[image: dev tools]

and this is the important part of my css code.

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  font: 16px/1.5 'PT Serif', Times, Cambria, serif;
  width: 580px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

#content p,
#content ul {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#content ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#content li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#content div.actions {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

#content div.actions .readmore {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

#content div.actions .readmore:hover {
  background-color: #389dc1;
  color: #fff;
}

#content div.actions .comments {
  color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.post {
  padding: 50px 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

.post .date {
  font: bold 12px 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #a7a7a7;
  margin: 24px 0 30px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.post .date:before {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -22px;
  top: -1px;
}

.post img {
  width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: width: 100%; doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here : [Width inherit on fixed div doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271787/width-inherit-on-fixed-div-doesnt-work/35272099)

The `inherit` keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.

Here you got a `p` tag in parent.

Comment: So I have to put inherit in every parent element until the one where width is defined?